# How to run UPDATE CONCAT in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

What is the OrientDB command equivalent to this MySQL statement?

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumnA = CONCAT(myColumnB, ' some string')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use append function to do the same

UPDATE myTable SET myColumnA = 
mycolumnB.append('somestring')